# CSS animation cancelling other style on svg

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, css-transforms, animate.css

I am attempting to both flip and animate an svg arrow. The flip transformation works. The animation (from animate.css) works. But when I combine the two, the animation seems to cancel out the flip transformation.

I've included the relevant code in this codepen: https://codepen.io/jgullick/pen/YzKgzaX

The svg arrow points to the right by default. I want to make it point left and shake at the same time.

HTML:

```
<svg class="flipLeft animated shake" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M7.33 24l-2.83-2.829 9.339-9.175-9.339-9.167 2.83-2.829 12.17 11.996z"/></svg>
```

CSS:

```
.flipLeft {
   -moz-transform: scaleX(-1) !important;
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1) !important;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) !important;
  transform: scaleX(-1) !important;
  filter: FlipH !important;
  -ms-filter: "FlipH" !important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake {
  from,
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  10%,
  30%,
  50%,
  70%,
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%,
  40%,
  60%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes shake {
  from,
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  10%,
  30%,
  50%,
  70%,
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%,
  40%,
  60%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }
}

.shake {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake;
  animation-name: shake;
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

Thanks

James

Comment: any individual element can only have one css property of a particular type applied to it.